# KDE Plasma freeze when I open System Monitor application

Tags: plasma

Recently I tried KDE Plasma. There is a problem with System Monitor, Desktop freeze when I open this application. First I installed Eos with  KDE plasma which recently released and then Kubuntu 23.10. My hardware is not recent. Actually very 15 years old.
Intel pentium Dual core 6.20
8 gb ram
160 HDD
NVIDIA gt 310.
I more thing to mention. Before KDE i tried other DE's too. Gnome and cinnamon. On these DE's there is not a such problem. But i think i like KDE's Plasma DE.
Sorry for very very bad english.

Comment: The question in your post is missing... Please edit your post and raise the question you have. So far, it is only a description of the problem ocuring.